# Timer in android intent service

Tags: java, android

i have a class to get notification from my server I don't use firebase cloud messaging so I am getting data with the intentservice class. However I want to check the notification in per 60 seconds but timer is not work in

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
```

it starts normally when I start the app but after that it doesn't check in time.

is there any way to check the notification every 60 seconds at the background ?

note: i don't use GCM firebase and I will never use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntentService starts the service when you send it an intent, runs whatever you define for that intent, then **ends the service**. If you are intending for the timer to be run then perhaps do it outside of the service. Perhaps you could use a Handler and post a delayed runnable firing the intent, although I must strongly **advise against this in the long term since doing 60 second checks using the phone's radio will drain its battery fast.** GCM's Firebase is meant to handle that issue since it "batches" the network requests, and if you don't want to do that then perhaps use a **JobScheduler**. Android manages the phone's radio pretty nicely and efficiently so unless 60 seconds is absolutely necessary, then it's not really advisable to do this; users could complain of battery drain.

On that handler thing:

```
private static Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper);
```

In your activity, then

```
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
            //Start your intent service here.
        } finally {
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 60000);
        }
    }
};
```

The try finally block is if your process somehow may trigger an error. If not necessary then you can remove it.

Then in your Activity's `onCreate()` or wherever you need to start the repeated trigger:

```
runnable.run();
```

Comment: thank you JobScheduler is useful ? as special for user batter ?

Comment: For JobScheduler to be effective it is inexact in nature; you define the job to be done and the rough time it needs to be done at, then Android will time it together with it's own system processes and other apps processes that need radio access. You can set the Job to be periodic when you describe it using JobInfo. These are the links you might want https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html#schedule(android.app.job.JobInfo)

Comment: thank you I read the article I don't have too much info about cloud messaging but I have a server and I can get the notification in sjonarray the problem is I am not sure which service should I use because as you say it can discharge user phone's batter.  I want to know your advice what do you think ? which service should I use? JobScheduler is fine  every 30 seconds at background ? firebase or alternative ? I don't want to use it because I think it is nonsense to use firebase system why should I share the notifications with Third person  I have a server  ?

Comment: As far as I know, Firebase helps to resolve the issue of your app polling the server constantly to check for updates. Your server tells it something's changed, Firebase handles the notification on it's own to the app. If you don't want to use it then setting a JobScheduler on repeat should be the best option. For a better guide check this out: https://medium.com/google-developers/scheduling-jobs-like-a-pro-with-jobscheduler-286ef8510129

Comment: I updated the class with jobService  so I had to increase minimum sdk level 16 to 21 anyway it is not problem. Can you write how to start ever 30 seconds in main activity ? Also  if you updated you post with job service example I think it will be useful for other user who look sfor the the same thing. Thank you very much again

Answer (score 1):

You can use Alarm manager

```
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);

   PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
   AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 60000, 60000, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: thanks for your post but this is a good method but it is not useful for my app because I will do too much work at the background so it will discharge the user battery